# WPF ComboBox text trimming

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, texttrimming

I want to show "..." at the end of the ComboBox content when its text is to large. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<!--this is App.xaml file-->

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
      <Style.Resources>
             <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
             </Style>
      </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

[How my ComboBox looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6anWc.png)

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibJxQ.png)

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This is how I add items to ComboBox:

```
SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        
adpt.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM foo", conn);
adpt.Fill(tbl);
comboBox1.Items.Add("");
foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
{
            ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
            item.Content = row["title"].ToString();
            item.Tag = row["id"].ToString();
            comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
tbl.Clear();
```

Comment: Are you populating the combobox inline in xml or are you setting the itemsource in code? Could you post your whole ComboBox xml?

Comment: @hYg-Cain Posted everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to add a Item-DataTemplate that contains a Textblock which again has the TextTrimming property. So add this ItemTempalte to your ComboBox1 in the corresponding xaml

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
              Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
              TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
            />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```